# Tailwindcss Background-Video with overlay

Tags: css, background, tailwind-css

I've been trying for some time to find a way to have a video as a background in a div which has an overlay making it darker. Also, there should be text in the div container, does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this in Tailwind?

[image]

I have presented the whole thing like this. Thanks for your ideas and help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `brightness-*` class utilities to darken the video applying the `filter` property without another element.

```
<video class="... brightness-50"></video>
```

Or if the element containing the text has the same width and height as the video, you can use the `backdrop-brightness-*` class utilities to apply the `backdrop-filter` to the div

```
<div class="w-full h-full backdrop-brightness-50">
   ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the video gives your div "volume", the easiest way is to use a structure like this:

```
https://play.tailwindcss.com/DS33YxNtF5
```

But there are a million ways to achieve something like this. Also. it depends a lot on various other factors that themselves depend on your page structure, etc.

I would refrain from adding opacity to the video because it can be heavy to continuously render.

Comment: https://play.tailwindcss.com/aZsP09cVLr

Comment: I have tested it here... the text isn't visible :(

Comment: the video tag wasn't closed, and it wasn't *-100 but *-full (my bad). Try now, it works perfectly

Comment: @Daniel did you make it eventually? Did you read my comment?